# Android: Controlling Wifi Range Potency

Tags: android, wifi

I am developing an android application and I would like to be able to control the range potency of my smartphone's wifi.

For example, suppose that I want to use the Wifi direct API, but I it shows me people that are in a range of 10 meters from me. Although this is very good, I just want to connect with people that are in a range of 3 meters from me. In this case my idea was to limit the potency of my smatphone's wifi, in order to only "see" the devices that are very near me.

My question in this case is: Is there anyway to limit/control the potency of the wifi device of my smartphone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WifiManager` exposes the `public WifiManager.WifiLock createWifiLock (int lockType, String tag)` method to allow for the application to claim a lock on the Wi-Fi in a certain mode, however, this is no mode that allow for the power to be decreased.  So the answer to your question is no.